# JMETER JDBCRequest call a storedprocedure with xml input

Tags: xml, database, jdbc, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

In JMETER JDBCRequest how can I call a storedprocedure with xml input variable,

The SP's input variable is defined as bellow:

IN PI_XML_DOC XML